# When was the --log-xml option dropped in phpunit?

Tags: phpunit, command-line-interface

`phpunit` had an option `--log-xml` in Version 3.2.8, but it vanished in version 3.7.24.

On the other side, Version 3.7.24 has an option `--log-junit`, which was not available in version 3.2.8 of `phpunit`. At what version(s) did the change occur?

As I cannot find a corresponding changelog or similar, I cannot answer this question myself.

Comment: You should be able to replace `--log-xml` with `--log-junit` in your command line to continue making use of the XML output format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHPUnit manuals contain the information:

- 3.3 (Sep 2008): http://phpunit.de/manual/3.3/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions

  - contains `--log-xml`
- 3.4 (Sep 2009): http://phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions

  - does not contain `--log-xml` but `--log-junit`